# "E: Unable to locate package update" when I try to update my system, why?

Tags: apt

I have almost an hour trying to update my installation, this is how I'm trying to do it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install update
[sudo] password for braiam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update
```

It just doesn't work! Isn't `install update` the text I should put after `sudo apt-get` to *install updates* on my Ubuntu system? If not, what command should I write?

> This question is trying to address some common mistakes by users not used to the APT system and `apt-get`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

APT tool `apt-get` has simple commands that you need to know before hand what they do, and in what circumstances use it.

If what you want is **update your packages list**, the correct command is:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

just that! You don't need to write anything else before nor after. Is just **sudo** + **apt-get** + **update**. Done.

**To install packages or programs** in your system, you **first need to know the package name**. If you don't know the package name is recommended you use a GUI (like Ubuntu Software Center or packagekit), search and install your program using it. If you know the package name then you only have to:

```
sudo apt-get install package_name
```

Replace `package_name` your package name. You can install several packages at once, just write them with an space between them. If you are still getting:

> E: Unable to locate package *package_name*

Then try updating your list or reviewing the instructions you are following, maybe is just a typographic mistake. If name of that package is unknown for apt-get that is the error you will get.

**For upgrading** the packages that you already have installed, aka update all your system, you need to do:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Nothing else. It will upgrade all the packages that you have installed in your system.

Comment: Try `apt-cache search <packagename>`,it will search for the related packages to the name given.